# Spring MVC app forwarding POST request to Webflow app

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

We have 2 web apps; a spring Mvc app which initially fronts a spring webflow app. The mvc app will forward a browser POST request to the webflow app and send the response back to the browser, subsequent browser interaction is then directly with the webflow app. The mvc app modifies the response with the new webflow app's context.

The problem I'm getting is that the webflow app is doing a POST-REDIRECT-GET. This results in an exception in the mvc app when I come to handle the response before responding to the browser. I'm thinking that I either need to prevent PRG for this flow request or steer clear of webflow in the webflow app for this initial request possibly using an mvc controller and starting webflow after this initial request.

Comment: "or steer clear of webflow in the webflow app for this initial request possibly using an mvc controller and starting webflow after this initial request" yes do that. Sounds like you are trying to 'hack' functionality that webflow wasn't designed for

Comment: Things have moved forward in that I'm using httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false) which has improved things but I seem to have the wrong uri root context (it's a pre F5 url initially posted to) on the response - I think some more response handling needed